# Reference multiple subfloated figures using \ref{X,Y,Z} to give Fig. 1a,1b,1c in text

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

I want to reference labels in the sentence, as above in the code: like this - \ref{X,Y,Z} to give "Fig. 1a,1b,1c" or "Fig. 1a-c" in text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}    
...in the three statistically favoured models (Fig.~\ref{fig:LocalPoly1_residual,   
fig:IDW2_residual, fig:RBF_residual}) discussed below and not as well in the case of 
GlobalPoly5 (Fig.~\ref{fig:GlobalPoly5_residual}).

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \subfloat[GlobalPoly5]{\label{fig:GlobalPoly5_residual}\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{"Data Analysis Files/GlobalPoly5_residual"}}                
  \subfloat[LocalPoly1]{\label{fig:LocalPoly1_residual}\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{"Data Analysis Files/LocalPoly1_residual"}}
  \subfloat[IDW2]{\label{fig:IDW2_residual}\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{"Data Analysis Files/IDW2_residual"}}
  \subfloat[RBF]{\label{fig:RBF_residual}\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{"Data Analysis Files/RBF_residual"}}
  \caption{Residual plots of each of the interpolators.}
  \label{fig:residualplot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

@Leo Liu : it gives a lower case "f" for "figs." - do you know how make it uppercase "F" for consistency with my labelling elsewhere?

Comment: This is _not_ a good question. What do you want to "work"? Please explain what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the title was sufficiently self-explanatory but perhaps I should be clearer.  I want to reference labels in the sentence, as above in the code: like this - \ref{X,Y,Z}.

Comment: I have to agree with @Seamus. The actual question should be stated in the body, not only in the title. "*Reference multiple labels*" can mean different things and the reader should not be forced to read the requested solution from the code!

Comment: Acknowledged, fixed.  Let me know if anything else needs to be edited for clarity.  Thanks.

Comment: What *exact* output do you want? Something like "Fig. 1a,b,c"?

Comment: I'm not too fussed about the exact form of the output, as long as it typographically, punctuationally and otherwise correct and clear. :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just use `\cref` or `\Cref` from [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package to reference multiple labels in one command.

For example, `\cref{fig1,fig2,fig3}` is valid. And use `\Cref` for capitals.

Comment: I don't think you can have the space after the comma. (At least that didn't work when I just tested.)

Comment: @Torbjorn: Indeed. It seems that `cleveref` should be impoved.

Comment: @Leo Liu : see my OP for a refinement request

Comment: @ptrcao: Use `\Cref`. And you'd better read the package manual first for details.

Comment: @Leo @ptrcao: `\Cref` is intended for the beginning of a sentence. To capitalize all refs, add the `capitalize` (or `capitalise`) option to the package, i.e. `\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}`. See the manual, section 5.

Comment: Thank you @Torbjorn for clarifying re capitalization and thanks @Leo Liu for proposing this solution.

Comment: I think it would be useful to post an entire example, including how to make the label that the cref references. It isn't intuitively obvious how to do this and/or if it is the same as you would do with just using \ref{}.

Answer (score 21):

without package `cleveref` the command must be `\ref{..},\ref{...}`

Comment: This didn't work for me

Comment: that is not a useful description of your problem ...

Comment: You're right.. What I meant is the following: If I have two theorems, say 1 and 2 labelled \label{first} and \label{second}, writing \ref{first}\ref{second} as you suggested will produce "12" and not "1,2", as the op was asking in his question.

Comment: Yes, it must be `\ref{...},\ref{...}`

Comment: Worked for me, and I don't an extra package. So, good!

Answer (score 3):

If you are already using the `cleveref` package and wish to only print the numbers of the references, you can use the `\labelcref` command to accomplish this.

`\labelcref{fig1,fig2,fig3}`

which will result in

`1a to 1c`

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do! (+1) The command `\cref` adds the type of reference (e.g., *Sect.*) to the labels.